# How to select max date with other columns grouped by only one specific column

Tags: mysql, group-by, jooq

I want to select the latest assignee for each order before `PRODUCTION_TASK_COMPLETED` (or the current one if the production task is not completed)

I can't find a way to get the latest assignee. As soon as the assignee changes, since I have to put all the columns in the `group by` clause which are not aggregated.

Here is something clause to what I want in MySQL (I need it in jooq but I'll rewrite it later)

```
SELECT 
    t_user.first_name,
    t_user.last_name,
    assigneehistory1.order_id,
    MAX(assigneehistory1.entry_date)
FROM
    t_entity_history_entry AS assigneehistory1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    t_user ON t_user.id = assigneehistory1.assignee_id
WHERE
    (assigneehistory1.entry_type = 'ORDER_ASSIGNED'
        AND assigneehistory1.entry_date <= COALESCE((SELECT 
                    MAX(assigneehistory2.entry_date)
                FROM
                    t_entity_history_entry AS assigneehistory2
                WHERE
                    (assigneehistory2.entry_type = 'PRODUCTION_TASK_COMPLETED'
                        AND assigneehistory2.order_id = assigneehistory1.order_id)),
            NOW()))
GROUP BY t_user.first_name , t_user.last_name , assigneehistory1.order_id
```

But as I said, this returns multiple rows for the same order for each different assignee, whereas I just want the latest one.

[image]

Comment: If you want to have one row for each separate `order_id` regardless of the values in other columns than you must group by this column only, not by 3 columns. Another 2 columns must be aggregated.

Comment: I cannot aggregate the other two columns. This is just an attempt to come close to the result I want, I know I have to rewrite this in order to achieve what I want, I just can't figure out how.

Comment: Test `SELECT MAX(t_user.first_name), MAX(t_user.last_name), assigneehistory1.order_id, MAX(assigneehistory1.entry_date) FROM ... GROUP BY assigneehistory1.order_id`. For your screenshot it will return `('Super', 'User', 3, '2021-08-16 16:44:49')`.